# Only using @JsonIgnore during serialization, but not deserialization

Tags: java, json, spring, annotations, jackson

I have a user object that is sent to and from the server. When I send out the user object, I don't want to send the hashed password to the client. So, I added `@JsonIgnore` on the password property, but this also blocks it from being deserialized into the password that makes it hard to sign up users when they don't have a password.

How can I only get `@JsonIgnore` to apply to serialization and not deserialization? I'm using Spring JSONView, so I don't have a ton of control over the `ObjectMapper`.

Things I've tried:

1. Add `@JsonIgnore` to the property
2. Add `@JsonIgnore` on the getter method only

Answer (score 672, accepted):

Exactly how to do this depends on the version of Jackson that you're using. This changed around version *1.9*, before that, you could do this by adding `@JsonIgnore` to the getter.

Which you've tried:

> Add @JsonIgnore on the getter method only

Do this, *and also* add a specific `@JsonProperty` annotation for your JSON "password" field name to the setter method for the password on your object.

More recent versions of Jackson have added `READ_ONLY` and `WRITE_ONLY` annotation arguments for `JsonProperty`. So you could also do something like:

```
@JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
private String password;
```

Docs can be found [here](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonProperty.Access.html).

Comment: https://gist.github.com/thurloat/2510887 for Jackson JSON ignore on **deserialize** only

Comment: It works, but I don't want a setter. I can make it no-op, but that feels wrong too. Also, the requirement of a default constructor breaks encapsulation. I just get a lot of dead setters in my code. But I suppose there is no way around this.

Comment: @Matt : Cant you use "transient" then ?

Comment: AFAIK you still have to implement the setter and annotate it. I just want the getter for serialization. What is the transient you speak of? That's a JPA annotation AFAIK

Comment: Also, make sure to remove @JsonProperty from the field itself otherwise it will override your getter/setter annotations

Comment: `@JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)`

Comment: Jackson-annotations 2.5 does not have the later feature. Jackson-annotations 2.6.3 does

Comment: http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonProperty.Access.html Yes the enum of Access in JsonProperty is since 2.6

Comment: Be careful, `JsonProperty` is `com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty`, `Access` is `com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty.Access` not  `javax.persistence.Access`, If you wrote code like `import javax.persistence.*;` the Access may not what you  want.

Answer (score 117):

In order to accomplish this, all that we need is two annotations:

1. `@JsonIgnore`
2. `@JsonProperty`

Use `@JsonIgnore` on the class member and its getter, and `@JsonProperty` on its setter. A sample illustration would help to do this:

```
class User {

    // More fields here
    @JsonIgnore
    private String password;

    @JsonIgnore
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    @JsonProperty
    public void setPassword(final String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

Comment: it's the only thing that worked for me with jackson 2.6.4. I tried my best to use @JsonProperty(access = Access.WRITE_ONLY) but it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 108):

Since version 2.6: a more intuitive way is to use the `com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty` annotation on the field:

```
@JsonProperty(access = Access.WRITE_ONLY)
private String myField;
```

Even if a getter exists, the field value is excluded from serialization.

JavaDoc says:

```
/**
 * Access setting that means that the property may only be written (set)
 * for deserialization,
 * but will not be read (get) on serialization, that is, the value of the property
 * is not included in serialization.
 */
WRITE_ONLY
```

In case you need it the other way around, just use `Access.READ_ONLY`.

Comment: I don't understand why there so few upvotes, this is elegant way to solve this problem, works like a charm. There is no need to annotate getter,setter and field. Only field.
Thanks.

Comment: This is available since version 2.6, see http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonProperty.Access.html

Comment: Probably the best answer for 2.6+ users.

Comment: Make sure you are not using the **org.codehaus.jackson.annotate** import. @DanielBeer's solution works for Jackson 2.6.3. This should be the accepted answer now that Jackson has been updated.

Comment: `WRITE_ONLY`, what a terrible name when your goal is to write your java object into a json file. `DESERIALIZE_ONLY` would be unambiguous

Answer (score 17):

In my case, I have Jackson automatically (de)serializing objects that I return from a Spring MVC controller (I am using @RestController with Spring 4.1.6). I had to use `com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore` instead of `org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonIgnore`, as otherwise, it simply did nothing.

Comment: this is an extremely useful answer that really helped me find the source of why @JsonIgnore was not being honored by Jackson... thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Another easy way to handle this is to use the argument `allowSetters = true` in the annotation. This will allow the password to be deserialized into your dto but it will not serialize it into a response body that uses contains object.

example:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(allowSetters = true, value = {"bar"})
class Pojo{
    String foo;
    String bar;
}
```

Both `foo` and `bar` are populated in the object, but only foo is written into a response body.

Comment: That was my mistake, I didn't realize you had already corrected the snippet. Looking at your changes, it appears my years of writing in Groovy got me and my translation to Java was a bit rough. Sorry!

Answer (score 3):

```json
    "user": {
        "firstName": "Musa",
        "lastName": "Aliyev",
        "email": "klaudi2012@gmail.com",
        "passwordIn": "98989898", (or encoded version in front if we not using https)
        "country": "Azeribaijan",
        "phone": "+994707702747"
    }
```

> ---

```java
    @CrossOrigin(methods = RequestMethod.POST)
    @RequestMapping("/public/register")
    public @ResponseBody MsgKit registerNewUsert(@RequestBody User u) {
    
        root.registerUser(u);
    
        return new MsgKit("registered");
    }
```

> ---

```java
    @Service
    @Transactional
    public class RootBsn {
    
        @Autowired UserRepository userRepo;
        
        public void registerUser(User u) throws Exception {
    
            u.setPassword(u.getPasswordIn());
            // Generate some salt and setPassword (encoded - salt + password)
            User u = userRepo.save(u);
    
            System.out.println("Registration information saved");
        }       
    }
```

> ---

```java
    @Entity
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"recordDate", "modificationDate", "status", "createdBy", "modifiedBy", "salt", "password"})
    public class User implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
                        
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
        private Long id;
                        
        private String country;
                        
        @Column(name = "CREATED_BY")
        private String createdBy;
                        
        private String email;
                        
        @Column(name = "FIRST_NAME")
        private String firstName;
                        
        @Column(name = "LAST_LOGIN_DATE")
        private Timestamp lastLoginDate;
                        
        @Column(name = "LAST_NAME")
        private String lastName;
                        
        @Column(name = "MODIFICATION_DATE")
        private Timestamp modificationDate;
                        
        @Column(name = "MODIFIED_BY")
        private String modifiedBy;
                        
        private String password;
                            
        @Transient
        private String passwordIn;
                        
        private String phone;
                        
        @Column(name = "RECORD_DATE")
        private Timestamp recordDate;
                                
        private String salt;
                        
        private String status;
                        
        @Column(name = "USER_STATUS")
        private String userStatus;
                        
        public User() {
        }

        // getters and setters
    }
```

Comment: It might help in future to give even a brief description of how the code works.

Comment: Alright !! What are you trying here ? Getting more votes ? lol

Answer (score 2):

You can use `@JsonIgnoreProperties` at the class level and put variables you want to ignore in JSON in the `value` parameter. Worked fine for me.

```java
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = { "myVariable1", "myVariable2" })
    public class MyClass {
          private int myVariable1;,
          private int myVariable2;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also do like:

```
@JsonIgnore
@JsonProperty(access = Access.WRITE_ONLY)
private String password;
```

It's worked for me

Comment: It will completely ignore. This is not what asked in question. JsonIgnore has precedence over JsonProperty.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for something similar. I still wanted my property serialized but wanted to alter the value using a different getter. In the below example, I'm deserializing the real password but serializing to a masked password. Here's how to do it:

```
public class User() {

    private static final String PASSWORD_MASK = "*********";

    @JsonIgnore
    private String password;

    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
    public String setPassword(String password) {
        if (!password.equals(PASSWORD_MASK) {
            this.password = password;
        }
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    @JsonProperty("password")
    public String getPasswordMasked() {
        return PASSWORD_MASK;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

The ideal solution would be to use DTO (data transfer object)

Comment: That is NOT ideal. It's just busy work that create parallel hierarchies which increases maintenance costs and bugs.

Comment: @chubbsondubs Ideal in the sense that it organizes a reliable contract. This, of course, comes with costs.