# Jackson mapper: ignore certain properties when writing?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I use JSON mapper to read an object from a string and then write the string from the object. I would like to be able to ignore some properties only when writing. What is the easiest way to accomplish this?

Comment: Are you using Spring?

Comment: Answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12505141/only-using-jsonignore-during-serialization-but-not-deserialization

Comment: Thanks eugen! Putting the JsonIgnore property ONLY on the getter is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 2):

On the interface you can use the `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)` annotation to ignore any fields that have not been specified.

For example:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
public static interface Point {
    double getLatitude();

    double getLongitude();
}
```

This will ignore any other fields that are serialized using the Point interface.

Comment: This did not do the trick. When I read the json object and write it to string it includes "property : null" for everything not set

Answer (score 1):

You can use @JsonProperty(access = Access.WRITE_ONLY) to ignore a property for serialization.

You can fine more information about this property at the below link.

https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonProperty.Access.html