# Is there any way to prevent field from deserialization in jackson?

Tags: java, spring, serialization, jackson

Is there any way to prevent a field from deserialization in jackson?
but i need to serialize that field
I tried with @jsonIgnoreProperties this prevent both serialization and deserialization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "trick" is to combine the @JsonProperty and @JsonIgnore on the setters and getters, like in the following example

```
 public class SerializeDemo{

      @JsonIgnore
      private String serializeOnly;


      @JsonProperty("serializeOnly")
      public String getSerializeOnly() {
        return serializeOnly;
      }

      @JsonIgnore
      public void setSerializeOnly(String serializeOnly) {
        this.serializeOnly= serializeOnly;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. Will try and let you know.

Comment: Yeah. It really does "The Trick". Thanks a lot

Comment: Now we have another issue. We cannot use @JsonIgnore in both setter and  the attribute. Our spring web project gives the following exception.    org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingException: Ambiguous mapping! Annotation JsonIgnore configured on field yyyyyy and one of its accessor methods in class XXXXXEntity! Any Idea??

Comment: Starting with Jackson 2.6 `@JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY)` should do, see [Frank Pavageau's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49321318/2032157)

Answer (score 4):

Starting with [Jackson 2.6](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson/wiki/Jackson-Release-2.6#annotations), a property can be marked as read- or write-only. It's simpler than hacking the annotations on both accessors and keeps all the information in one place:

```java
public class NoDeserialization {
    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY)
    private String prop;

    public String getProp() {
        return prop;
    }

    public void setProp(String prop) {
        this.prop = prop;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@JsonIgnore` om field declaration.

ex.

```
@JsonIgnore
private Integer fieldToPrevent; // this will be avoided

private Integer regularField; // will serialize
```

look [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12505141/only-using-jsonignore-during-serialization-but-not-deserialization#12505165) a explanation of it.

[I have gave same answer here also.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23101260/ignore-fields-from-java-object-dynamically-while-sending-as-json-from-spring-mvc/23101380#23101380)