# How map Child Object input json in jackson?

Tags: java, json, hibernate, spring-mvc, jackson

I'm developing an application using java with [hibernate 4.2.6](http://hibernate.org) and [spring 4.0.1](http://spring.io). My application is a `REST FULL` application. for this I use jackson. My entities are as follow:

Calk.java:

```
@Entity
public class Calk {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="calk", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    List<BaseLayer> baseLayer = new ArrayList<BaseLayer>();
    
    public void addBaseLayer(BaseLayer baseLayer){
        this.baseLayer.add(baseLayer);
    }
    
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public List<BaseLayer> getBaseLayer() {
        return baseLayer;
    }
    public void setBaseLayer(List<BaseLayer> baseLayer) {
        this.baseLayer = baseLayer;
    }
}
```

BaseLayer.java:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
@JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include=JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property="layer")
@JsonSubTypes(
{
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value=PointLayer.class, name="point")
})
@DiscriminatorValue("BaseLayerDiscriminator")
public class BaseLayer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    protected Long gid;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    protected Calk calk;

    public Long getGid(){
        return gid;
    }

    public void setGid(Long gid){
        this.gid = gid;
    }
    
    @JsonIgnore
    public Calk getCalk(){
        return calk;
    }

    public void setCalk(Calk calk){
        this.calk = calk;
    }
}
```

Now I have a class that extends from `BaseLayer.java` as follow:
PointLayer.java:

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("PointDiscriminator")
public class PointLayer extends BaseLayer{
    
    private String name;
    
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Now I create a json as follow and then send it to a controller:

```
{"layer": "point", "calk":{"id":1}, "name": "itsme"}
```

Now the controller defines as follow:

```
@RequestMapping("\test")
public String test(@RequestBody BaseLayer baseLayer){
   System.out.println(baseLayer.getName());// this print "itsme"
   Calk calk = baseLayer.getCalk();//it return null
   if(calk == null)
      return "its null";
   else
      return "its not null";
}
```

when we call the controller it return `its not null`. The `calk` should not be `null`.

Where is the problem?

**Update**:
When I remove `@JsonIgnore` at `getCalk`, It work fine. But Why? I want to ignore `getCalk` but NOT ignore `setCalk`.

Comment: you mean to say you want to set the value of `calk` but you dont want to get that value?

Comment: I want to insert `baseLayer` record, and I want to know this `baseLayer` is which one of `calk`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12505141/only-using-jsonignore-during-serialization-but-not-deserialization this may help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@JsonIgnore` in follow:

```
@JsonIgnore
public List<BaseLayer> getBaseLayer() {
    return baseLayer;
}
```

set Ignore to following by default:

```
public void setBaseLayer(List<BaseLayer> baseLayer) {
    this.baseLayer = baseLayer;
}
```

You must add `@JsonProperty("baseLayer")` On top of set function as follow:

```
@JsonProperty("baseLayer")
public void setBaseLayer(List<BaseLayer> baseLayer) {
    this.baseLayer = baseLayer;
}
```