# In Spring data rest how to allow user to set value but ignore it in get request

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

In scenario where I'm exposing following entity in Spring data rest:

```
public class User implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "user_id")
private Long userId;

@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 50)
@Column(length = 50, unique = true, nullable = false)
private String username;

@JsonIgnore
@NotNull
@Size(min = 60, max = 60)
@Column(name = "password",length = 60)
private String password;
....
```

I would like password to not be exposed in the response when performing GET on ../users/1
but allowing hal browser to know that when performing post request it needs to set password.

When I'm using @JsonIgnore Hal Browser do not know that it needs to set password field:

[image: hal browser post request]

How can I do it? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding `@JsonIgnore` in the getter method only instead of the `private String password` property?

```
...

@NotNull
@Size(min = 60, max = 60)
@Column(name = "password",length = 60)
private String password;

...

@JsonIgnore
public String getPassword(){
    return this.password;
}


public void setPassword(String password){
    this.password = password;
}
```

Edit: I just found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12505141/only-using-jsonignore-during-serialization-but-not-deserialization)

Answer (score 0):

Just use the property `access` of `@JsonIgnore`.

`@JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)`

You don't need to place it in the getter.

Hope it helps.