# Difficulty in mapping java object to JSON

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am trying to map JSON to java object and vice-versa. In doing so, my unknown parameters for the class are mapped into `java.util.Map` by `@JsonAnySetter` method. But at the time of getting back the json from java object I am getting wrong output. I am using fasterxml library.

Here is my java object:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnyGetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnySetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class TestClass {
    private String context_id;
    private Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<>();

    public String getContext_id() {
        return context_id;
    }
    public void setContext_id(String context_id) {
        this.context_id = context_id;
    }
    @JsonAnySetter
    public void set(String fieldName, String value){
        this.properties.put(fieldName, value);
    }
    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, String> any() {
        return this.properties;
    }
    public String get(String fieldName){
        return this.properties.get(fieldName);
    }
}
```

and the JSON I am providing to map into java object by `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper` is:

```
{
    "context_id": "14",
    "io": "odp"
}
```

and when I try to get the JSON back from java object I am getting like this:

```
{
            "context_id": "14",
            "properties" : {
                   "io": "odp"
             },
            "io": "odp"
}
```

But I should get it back like:

```
{
        "context_id": "14",
        "properties" : {
               "io": "odp"
         }
}
```

which I am not getting.

Comment: Did you really mean your expected output, or do you want output similar to your input?

Comment: Yes, I mean so. My expected output is - 
`{
        "context_id": "14",
        "properties" : {
               "io": "odp"
         }
}`

Answer (score 0):

Remove the get-method and all should be fine. As an alternative you could set @JsonIgnore on the getter (see
 [Only using @JsonIgnore during serialization, but not deserialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12505141/only-using-jsonignore-during-serialization-but-not-deserialization)).

Comment: If I remove the get method I won't be able to get the unknown parameters that have been stored into map, I want my output like this -
`{
        "context_id": "14",
        "properties" : {
               "io": "odp"
         }
}`
not this - 
`{
        "context_id": "14",
        "properties" : {
               "io": "odp"
         },
        "io": "odp"
}`

Comment: Sure. Have you tried it using the above mentioned answer?

Comment: yup. for that i got my json as 
`{"context_id":"12","yio":"odjp"}`
not as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your help. I have solved the problem.
 1. I have removed this portion

```
@JsonAnyGetter
public Map<String, String> any() {
    return properties;
}
```

2. Add a normal getter for the properties map like -

   public Map getProperties() {
      return properties;
   }