# how to restrict access some fields of child entities and parent entities through spring rest api

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc

if I hit an API that is displaying all the details of child entities with parent entity [Mapping may OneToOne or ManyToOne etc..]. I am getting output like this..

```
{
  "fID": 19,
  **"comments": "good",**
  "recommendation": "rec",
  "candidate": {
    "candidateID": 400,
    "firstName": "Raghu",
    "lastName": "R",
    "emailID": "emial@gmail.com",
    "phoneNumber": "9900000099",
    **"password": "Hello",**
    "gender": "1",
    "candidateDOB": 1472169600000,
    "userId": 22
  },
  "inter": {
    "interID": 14,
    **"name": "Anu",**
    "designation": "Dev"
  },
  "Job": {
    "id": 13,
    "maxYearOfExperience": 9,
    "minYearOfExperience": 3,
    **"organizationName": "EFG"**    
  }
}
```

my code is:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("from EntityName where ID= :id");
             query.setInteger("id", id);
             result = query.uniqueResult();
```

I want to hide displaying the fields, bold letters [**    **] in the above output..
I tried some methods, :

1st method is :

```
EntityName example = new EntityName();              
                Example ex = Example.create(example).excludeProperty("password");               
                Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(EntityName.class)
                                           .add(Restrictions.eq("id", id))
                                           .add(ex);
                EntityName= (EntityName) criteria.uniqueResult();
```

But this approach is not working as my requirement.

2nd method is:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(EntityName.class)
                                          .add(Restrictions.eq("id", id));
                ProjectionList projList = Projections.projectionList();
                projList.add(Projections.property("id"));
                projList.add(Projections.property("Name"));
                projList.add(Projections.property("authPerson"));
              projList.add....so on
                criteria.setProjection(projList);

                Object obj =  criteria.uniqueResult();
                if(obj != null){
                EntityName= (EntityName) obj;               
                }
```

Is there any other way to solve this? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using the @JsonIgnore and @JsonProperty annotations inside your parent entity. How exactly you do this will depend on what version of Jackson you are using. Have a look at this answer for the options you have:

[Only using @JsonIgnore during serialization, but not deserialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12505141/only-using-jsonignore-during-serialization-but-not-deserialization)

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer :

```
More fields....

    @JsonIgnore
    private String password;

    @JsonIgnore
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    @JsonProperty
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
```

this will restrict the property.
Thanks,