# Spring Data Rest - hide instead of exposing ID

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, entity

I have en entity class which has an natural ID field mapped as `@Id` and I don't have any surrogate ID(invented field only for table ID) field. And, in the Jackson marshalled JSON I see an extra `id` exposed.

So instead of:

```
{
    "bin":"123456", ...
}
```

I see:

```
{
    "id":"123456", "bin":"123456", ...
}
```

which I don't want because they are repeated information. How can I prevent this?

I haven't touched REST/MVC configuration adapter; they are for exposing the ID classes, but I don't want that.

Bean:

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name="bin_info")
public class BinInfo implements Serializable, Persistable<String> {
    @Id
    @NotBlank //this is for absent parameter. Not equal to Pattern regex check
    @Pattern(regexp = "^\\d{6,8}$") //6-8 digits
    @Column(name="bin")
    @JsonProperty("bin")
    private String bin;

    ...
```

I am with these dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-undertow')
    runtime('com.h2database:h2')
    runtime('org.postgresql:postgresql')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    testCompile('io.cucumber:cucumber-java:3.0.2')
    testCompile('io.cucumber:cucumber-junit:3.0.2')
    testCompile('io.cucumber:cucumber-spring:3.0.2')
}
```

Spring Boot 2.0.3.

Comment: Check these post if it helps you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23101260/ignore-fields-from-java-object-dynamically-while-sending-as-json-from-spring-mvc
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12505141/only-using-jsonignore-during-serialization-but-not-deserialization

Comment: try to comment @JsonProperty("bin") and check

Comment: Annotate property as @JsonProperty(access = Access.WRITE_ONLY)
private String bin;

Comment: Very late comment: I am guessing the mysterious Id field originates from the Persistable interface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all, I think it has to do with some configuration of Spring or Jackson that will automatically expose the field mapped with `@Id`. I can just guess because no time for a confirmation.

And some colleague suggests me to define a DTO instead of putting the `@Jsonxxx` annotations in the class, saying the model represents data model and are related to the table, while DTO is related with view layer. So I did it and now all is fine.

Now the model is free of `id` field and `@JsonProperty`/`@JsonIgnore`:

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name="bin_info")
public class BinInfo implements Serializable, Persistable<String> {
    @Id
    @NaturalId
    @NotBlank //this is for absent parameter. Not equal to Pattern regex check
    @Pattern(regexp = "^\\d{6,8}$") //6-8 digits
    @Column(name="bin")
    //@JsonProperty("bin")
    private String bin;

    ...
```

And the DTO is totally without `@Id`:

```
@Data
public class BinInfoDTO {
    @JsonProperty("bin")
    private String bin;

    @JsonProperty("json_full")
    private String json_full;

    ...
```

When I retrieve an entity, with a mapping method I set all values I need in a DTO to the DTO and return it to the endpoint. Then the JSON is normal and fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try annotating with `@NaturalId` instead of `@Id`.

Comment: No, it does not work. If I only uses `NaturalID`, it complains about "No identifier". If I use `@Id` and `@NaturalID` on the same field, I still get `id` key in the JSON.

Comment: So you use a surrogate key and place json ignore on it. And then use this as 
`@NaturalId` on bin? Not too sure about this workaround. Seems like there must be a efficient solution

Comment: I didn't add a surrogate ID; I just tried to add `@Id` and `@NaturalId` on `bin`, but (1)with @NaturalID; (2) with ID and NaturalID, they neither work.

Comment: What I was suggesting was this: https://gist.github.com/aliahsan07/c6b949d71f775a7538063bcdfe68c96d

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement the get and set from id field.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Try annotating that field with `@JsonIgnore`

Comment: Hm... I want to show `bin` in the json... and there is nothing to ignore because `id` is not a field in the bean.

Comment: Since this is a Spring Data Rest project (meaning your data entities are your api object responses), you might have to create a filter to parse the ID fields.