# Hide property while Response return, but should be available with ObjectMapper operations

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson

I have a POJO class with certain properties.
I want a property to be hidden when its returned as JSON via REST api(Spring Boot).
But it should be available when I used ObjectMapper's writeValueAsBytes/readValue method.
How can I do this?

```
Pojo object = objectMapper.readValue(stream,Pojo.class);//should be available
objectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(pojoObject)//should write that property too
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Only using @JsonIgnore during serialization, but not deserialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12505141/only-using-jsonignore-during-serialization-but-not-deserialization)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SimpleBeanPropertyFilter` in spring boot :

```
SimpleBeanPropertyFilter filter = SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.filterOutAllExcept("field2", "field3");
FilterProvider filters = new SimpleFilterProvider().addFilter("SomeBeanFilter", filter);
MappingJacksonValue mapping = new MappingJacksonValue(list);
mapping.setFilters(filters);
return mapping;
```

See more details at https://www.concretepage.com/jackson-api/jackson-jsonfilter-example