# Issue while deserializing a serialized object

Tags: java, kotlin, jackson, deserialization

- I have a kotlin data class, having a parameterized constructor, and a method which derives its output based on a property.
- I have annotated this method with @JsonProperty so that its derived output can also be serialized to output JSON, as that was a requirement to me.
- Now the issue arises when I try to deserialize this JSON, and it doesn't find any field for the derivedProp

> Cannot construct instance of `MyDataClass`, problem: Should never call
>   `set()` on setterless property ('derivedProp')

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = false)
data class MyDataClass(
   val boolProp: Boolean = true,
   val dataProp: DataProp = DataProp(),
   val mainProp: String? = null
) : Serializable {

   @JsonProperty
   @Suppress("unused")
   fun derivedProp(): List =
      someLogicOnMainProp(mainProp)

}
```

Comment: `val` defines immutable variables, so there is not setter for a val. Using `var` instead of `val` will fix the issue

Comment: issue is not for the 3 properties declared as val, it is for the forth one, which is created at the time of serialization due to the method derivedProp()

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Only using @JsonIgnore during serialization, but not deserialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12505141/only-using-jsonignore-during-serialization-but-not-deserialization)

Comment: could you please explain, how ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem using the below property on @JsonProperty annotation:

```
@JsonProperty(access = Access.WRITE_ONLY)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use a property instead of a function, you can still define a setter and just ignore it, when it's called. Not the prettiest solution, but should do the trick:

```
@get:JsonProperty
var derivedProp: List<Any>
    get() = someLogicOnMainProp(mainProp)
    set(value) { /* do nothing */ }
```

Comment: This could be a workaround, but that will be at a cost of data redundancy at run-time,  looking for a better solution :-)

Comment: I don't quite follow, how will it be redundant? Instead of a function, you now just have a property.

Comment: because the data will be redundant (mainProp, and derivedProp)

Comment: Well no it won't, because derivedProp is just a function you call on mainProp. It is not seperately stored...