# Selectively @JsonIgnore Immutables accessor methods, ONLY during serialization or deserialization using Jackson

Tags: java, jackson, jackson-databind, immutables-library

This is definitely not a duplicate of [Only using @JsonIgnore during serialization, but not deserialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12505141/only-using-jsonignore-during-serialization-but-not-deserialization). The problem is the same but in the context of [Immutables](https://immutables.github.io/).

When a model(DTO/DAO) is decorated as an Immutable, I am not able to selectively @JsonIgnore one of the properties during serialization. Suppose that we have a UserDto which is defined as an Immutable as follow

```
@Value.Immutable
@Value.Style(defaults = @Value.Immutable(copy = false), init = "set*")
@JsonSerialize(as = ImmutableUserDto.class)
@JsonDeserialize(builder = ImmutableUserDto.Builder.class)
public abstract class UserDto {

    @JsonProperty("id")
    @Value.Default
    public int getId() {
        return 0;
    }

    @JsonProperty("username")
    public abstract String getUsername();

    @JsonProperty("email")
    public abstract String getEmail();

    @JsonProperty("password")
    public abstract String getPassword();
}
```

I believe it is fair to expect that during serialization we would want to ignore the `password` from the response of the service.

Without using Immutables if we were working with a simple class, then there are many ways to accomplish this. For example - annotate only the getter with `@JsonIgnore`. Or if possible define a different accessor method (something that doesn't have the get prefix) and only define the regular setter method... and so on.

If I try the same on the Immutables accessor method for the password as shown below:

```
@Value.Immutable
@Value.Style(defaults = @Value.Immutable(copy = false), init = "set*")
@JsonSersonIgnoreialize(as = ImmutableUserDto.class)
@JsonDeserialize(builder = ImmutableUserDto.Builder.class)
public abstract class UserDto {

    ....

    @JsonProperty("password")
    @JsonIgnore
    public abstract String getPassword();
}
```

then, the generated ImmutableUserDto adds the @JsonIgnore on both the getter and setter as shown below.

```
@Generated(from = "UserDto", generator = "Immutables")
@SuppressWarnings({"all"})
@ParametersAreNonnullByDefault
@javax.annotation.Generated("org.immutables.processor.ProxyProcessor")
@Immutable
@CheckReturnValue
public final class ImmutableUserDto extends UserDto {
  ...
  ...
  private final String password;

  ...
  ...

  /**
   * @return The value of the {@code password} attribute
   */
  @JsonProperty("password")
  @JsonIgnore
  @Override
  public String getPassword() {
    return password;
  }

  ...
  ...
  ...

  @Generated(from = "UserDto", generator = "Immutables")
  @NotThreadSafe
  public static final class Builder {

    ...
    ...

    private String password;

    @JsonProperty("password")
    @JsonIgnore
    public final Builder setPassword(String password) {
      this.password = password;
      return this;
    }
  }
}
```

Serialization will work as expected. The `password` attribute will be excluded from the JSON. But when I try to de-serialize, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot build UserDto, some of the required attributes are not set [password]
```

Which is obvious as Immutables added the `@JsonIgnore` to the setter as well.

The [documentation](https://immutables.github.io/json.html) isn't of much help. In their *Things to be aware of* section, it just mentions the following regarding `@JsonIgnore`

> If using @JsonIgnore, you should explicitly make an attribute
>   non-mandatory. In Immutables, an attribute can be declared as 
>   non-mandatory via @Nullable, Optional or @Value.Default which are all
>   different in their effect and we do not derive anything automatically.

Using `@Nullable` or `Optional` or `@Value.Default` is not of any use in case of fields like `password`.

I have gone through the issue list on their GitHub page and there is a [similar issue](https://github.com/immutables/immutables/issues/503)  but the user was asking for a slightly different use case and using @Nullable could solve the problem which doesn't work in my case.

I have also tried to use one of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34158302/4054389). Still resulted in the same error.

It looked like this is not supported by Immutables library. I have created a [new issue](https://github.com/immutables/immutables/issues/969) myself. Once I get some feedback from users on SOF, I will probably create a [sscce](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: You should be able to use the `@JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)` annotation that you linked to in order to avoid serializing the password value. I've used that successfully with immutables to affect the serialization or deserialization of a field via Jackson.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had to use the suggestion given by @benarena in this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55965304/selectively-jsonignore-immutables-accessor-methods-only-during-serialization-o#comment98731877_55965304). However I had to explicitly specify the value attribute of the property along with the Access attribute.

`@JsonProperty(value = "password", access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)` solved the problem.

The Immutable class would look like:

```
@Value.Immutable
@Value.Style(defaults = @Value.Immutable(copy = false), init = "set*")
@JsonSersonIgnoreialize(as = ImmutableUserDto.class)
@JsonDeserialize(builder = ImmutableUserDto.Builder.class)
public abstract class UserDto {

    ....

    @JsonProperty(value = "password", access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
    public abstract String getPassword();
}
```