# Only using @JsonIgnore during deserialization, but not serialization in generation of swagger docs

Tags: java, jackson, annotations, swagger, swagger-2.0

I am trying to ignore a property while deserialization, but not serialization.

I have a property(`specType`) which is not required for the client to send but while retrieval client should be able to see that property. Means, while GET they should be able to see but while POST they should not see specType.

I tried following combinations but non of them worked. I am using jackson-annotaion 2.9.0

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty.Access;

public class A1 {

    @JsonProperty(access = Access.READ_ONLY)
    private String specType;

    public String getSpecType() {
        return specType;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public void setSpecType(String specType) {
        this.specType = specType;
    }


}
```

==

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

public class A1 {

    @JsonIgnore
    private String specType;

    @JsonProperty("specType")
    public String getSpecType() {
        return specType;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public void setSpecType(String specType) {
        this.specType = specType;
    }

}
```

==

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = { "specType" }, allowGetters = true)
public class A1 {

    private String specType;

    public String getSpecType() {
        return specType;
    }

    public void setSpecType(String specType) {
        this.specType = specType;
    }

}
```

I am using swagger following swagger versions:
`springfox-swagger-ui version 2.9.2
springfox-swagger2 version 2.9.2`
Am I missing anything?

Comment: As noted adding `@JsonProperty(access = Access.READ_ONLY)` **and only this** (e.g. remove the `@JsonIgnore` on the setter) should work.

Comment: Opposite of what you asked: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12505141/2987755

Comment: @dkb Oposite to that only I tried. But no luck till now.

Comment: @AlanHay Only `@JsonProperty(access = Access.READ_ONLY)` also did't worked for me.

Comment: is your question around generation of swagger docs as opposed to the actual functionality?

Comment: works for me `A1 a1 = new A1();`
        `a1.setSpecType("Hello");`
        `a1.setId(1);`
        `String str = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(a1);`
        `System.out.println(str);// {"id":1,"specType":"Hello"}`

        `A1 a2 = objectMapper.readValue(str, A1.class);`
        `System.out.println(a2.getId() +":"+a2.getSpecType()); // 1 : null`

Comment: As you can see above, I am able to serialize `specType` but during deserialization, `specType` is `null`

Comment: @AlanHay Yes! This question is regarding generation of swagger docs only.

Comment: **CAN YOU MAKE THAT CLEAR IN THE TITLE AND TEXT OF YOUR QUESTION THEN!**