# How do I know what implementation of jaxrs I am using?

Tags: java, jax-rs

I have a Java 1.7 starts application. It does have some RESTful api's.

I would like to add `@JsonIgnore` to a filed so that it is not returned in the api.

E.g.

### Member.java

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
    
private java.lang.String username;
@JsonIgnore
private java.lang.String password;
```

Does not ignore the password.

```
"member": {
    "password": "**************",
    "username": "richard"
}
```

I think the reason why `@JsonIgnore` does not work, is because I use `com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore`. Should I use a different annotation from a different library? i.e. Is my implementation of jaxrs maybe not `com.fasterxml.jackson`?  How do I tell?

The IntelliJ classpath has:

[image]

(I have tried `net.minidev.json.annotate.JsonIgnore` with no success)

More info:

### pom.xml

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.minidev</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-smart</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
</dependency>
```

and

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.2</version>
</dependency>
```

[image]

Is this the problem? two versions!  I am not sure where the 2.0.5 version comes from, as it is not defined in the pom.

[image]

Comment: Maybe add the annotation to either the accessor (get) or mutator (set) method, but not both. I suggest the getter for readability.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl thanks for the reply. I have tried adding it to the getter, with no joy.

Comment: Take a look here: [Only using @JsonIgnore during serialization, but not deserialization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12505165/1762224) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27386343/1762224) for more advice.

Comment: Thanks.  I try `@JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)`, but it doesn't compile: `Cannot resolve symbol 'Access'`.

Comment: I think this is because it does not exist in version `2.0.5`.

Comment: Take a look at the second one. It suggests using both `@JsonIgnore` and `@JsonProperty` in tandem.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl unfortunately using both `@JsonIgnore` and `@JsonProperty` in tandem does not work either, I still get the `password` in the json.

Comment: I think the reason is because it is using `2.0.5` to do the ignore, but jaxrs is using `2.11.2` to build the json. I just don't know why there is a version `2.0.5` as it's not in any pom.  edit: there included projects that use `2.0.5`.

Comment: What server are you using? There are no guarantees that the jax-rs provider is using Jackson (though very likely it must be). Jersey does use Jackson, though, so this should be working. One thing I would try is package `org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonIgnore`. This is the package name Jackson used a long time ago before they moved to the package you are using. Doesn't hurt to try...

Comment: @MarcioLucca thanks for the reply.  I am using `jboss-as-7.0.2.Final`. I do not have `org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonIgnore` in my classpath though.

Comment: If I change all my dependencies to `2.0.5`. I get the following exception when jaxrs tries to build the json: `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a @JsonIgnore in this case. You can simply omit the variable that you don't want deserialized(the password in this case) and jackson will just return you the username.

Comment: I don't want to omit `password`, because this is an entity used by Hibernate and it writes `password`. I just want to ignore it when I read it.

Comment: @Richard Then I suggest not mixing domain entities (ORM) with data translation units (DTO or POJO) objects. Map your database object to a DTO and exclude the password entirely.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl - you are correct.  I should not be using the entity.

Comment: Thinking about this again, maybe the annotations did not work because JPA/Hibernate do not return the actual classes you create, they will return proxies to your classes. So maybe the proxy classes will not be annotated the same way as the actual classes. Just a theory. It would be interesting to do a unit test to  try to explicitly JSON serialize entities returned from the database using Jackson, to see if Jackson can pick up the annotations.