# Empty List obtained in the Controller function for a POST request SpringBoot HIbernate

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, rest

I'm creating an e-commerce shopping platform.

I've the following 3 entity classes:

1. ProductInventory
2. Orders
3. OrderedProduct

   @Entity
   @Getter
   @Setter
   @NoArgsConstructor
   @AllArgsConstructor
   public class ProductInventory {

   ```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long productId;

    private String name;

    private Double price;

    private Long availableQty;

    private String description;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Category category;
   ```

   }

   @Entity
   @Getter
   @Setter
   @NoArgsConstructor
   @AllArgsConstructor
   public class Orders {

   ```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long orderId;

    private String userEmail;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="dd/MM/yyyy")
    private Date orderDate;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="dd/MM/yyyy")
    private Date deliveryDate;

    private double bill;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL , mappedBy = "orders")
    private List<OrderedProduct> orderedProductList = new ArrayList<>();
   ```

   }

   @Entity
   @Setter
   @Getter
   @NoArgsConstructor
   @AllArgsConstructor
   @JsonIdentityInfo(property = "id",generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class)
   public class OrderedProduct {

   ```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private Long orderedProductId;

    private Long quantityOrdered;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false , fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ORDEREDPRODUCT_ID")
    private Orders orders;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false , fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_product_id")
    private ProductInventory product;
   ```

   }

I've the following controller to accept POST requests.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/orders")
public class OrderController {

    @Autowired
    private OrderService orderService;


    @PostMapping(value = "/placeOrder")
    public ResponseEntity<String> createUserRequest(@RequestBody Orders newOrder) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("NewOrder ID = "+ newOrder.getOrderId());
        System.out.println("NewOrder UserEmail = "+ newOrder.getUserEmail());
        System.out.println("NewOrder ORDERDATE = "+ newOrder.getOrderDate());
        System.out.println("NewOrder DELIVERYDATE = "+ newOrder.getDeliveryDate());
        System.out.println("NewOrder BILL = "+ newOrder.getBill());
        System.out.println("NewOrder List = "+ newOrder.getOrderedProductList());

        return orderService.createOrder(newOrder);
    }
}
```

When I send the following **POST** request :

```
{
    "userEmail": "new order",
    "orderDate": "09/03/2022",
    "deliveryDate": "09/04/2022",
    "bill": 80,
    "orderedProductList": [
        {
            "orderedProductId": 1,
            "quantityOrdered": 3
        }
    ]
}
```

I get the following as the output in the console:

```
NewOrder ID = null
NewOrder UserEmail = new order
NewOrder ORDERDATE = Wed Mar 09 05:30:00 IST 2022
NewOrder DELIVERYDATE = Sat Apr 09 05:30:00 IST 2022
NewOrder BILL = 80.0
NewOrder List = [] --------------------I'm more concerned about this list being empty inside the controller
Inside OrderService 
Bill : 80.0
The number of ordered products are as follows : 0
```

I tried doing POST request when the product with given id is present as well as absent in the table.
Both the time it returned the same result in the console.

I also tried doing the POST by removing the `"quantityOrdered": 3` from the JSON, but again I was getting the same result. **The data is getting saved in the MySqlDB but the List is empty each time.**

I'm unable to find out where I'm making the mistake.

Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @JsonIgnore on that field. Remove that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have @JsonIgnore on that field so it will not be deserialized.

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12505141/only-using-jsonignore-during-serialization-but-not-deserialization).