# Ignore field with annotation for JSON serialization but not for Mongo in MongoJack

Tags: mongo-jackson-mapper

Is there any possibility to ignore field for JSON serialization (for web display) but not for mongo (internal serialization) ?

I`ve tried so far all these methods but field was also ignored for Mongo, or not ignored in both in case of some variations

[Jackson: how to prevent field serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9112900/jackson-how-to-prevent-field-serialization)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I finally solved this.

```
objectMapper.writerWithView(Views.Public.class).writeValueAsString(lo));
```

writeValueUsingView is from another version of Jackson, so it wasn't working

Answer (score 0):

Custom serialization for web/mongo can be solved by using @JsonView annotations, try along these lines:

```
class Views {
    static class OnAllViews {}
    static class OnlySomeViews extends OnAllViews {}
    ...
}

public class Thing {
    @JsonView(Views.OnAllViews.class) Integer id;
    @JsonView(Views.OnlySomeViews.class) String name;
}
```

and then you can call the appropriate level of serialization through `writeValueUsingView` method.

```
objectMapper.writeValueUsingView(out, beanInstance, ViewsPublic.class);
```

You can read more about it [here](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonJsonViews).

Comment: Thx for reply! I've already tried this, but it's not working for me.

`@JsonView(Views.Internal.class)
private String password;`

and then:
`ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.readerWithView(Views.Public.class);
Landlord g = collection.findOneById(j.get("_id").asText());
return mapper.readerForUpdating(g).readValue(j.toString());`