# Unsatisfied dependencies for type ResourceBundle with qualifiers @Bundle

Tags: jsf, cdi, inject, resourcebundle

Based on the proposed solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51834221/1227941), I am trying to use CDI @Produces to be able to access with @Inject multiple properties files:

**Bundle Interface**

```
package com.locale;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;
import javax.enterprise.util.Nonbinding;
import javax.inject.Qualifier;

@Qualifier
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Bundle {

    @Nonbinding
    public String value() default "";
}
```

**BundleProducer Class**

```
package com.locale;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Produces;
import javax.enterprise.inject.spi.InjectionPoint;

public class BundleProducer implements Serializable{

    @Produces
    @Bundle
    public ResourceBundle loadBundle(InjectionPoint ip) {
        String bundleName = ip.getAnnotated().getAnnotation(Bundle.class).value();
        ResourceBundle res = ResourceBundle.getBundle(bundleName);
        return res;
    }
}
```

**The class where I inject my bundle:**

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class PasswordBean implements Serializable {

    @Inject @Bundle("com.locale.admin.user")
    private ResourceBundle uiResources;

    public String chgPassword() {
        if (currentPwd isNotOk) {
            FacesMessage fm = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, uiResources.getString("cpwdIncorrect"), "");
            ctx.addMessage(null, fm);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

**The Exception:**

```
Exception while loading the app : CDI deployment failure:WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type ResourceBundle with qualifiers @Bundle
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject @Bundle private com.security.PasswordBean.uiResources
  at com.security.PasswordBean.uiResources(PasswordBean.java:0)
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type ResourceBundle with qualifiers @Bundle
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject @Bundle private com.security.PasswordBean.uiResources
```

Any help please.

Comment: From the little code you provided it seems that the producer is not found (aka. the class which declares it is not recognized as bean), do you have `beans.xml`? Try annotating your `BundleProducer` class with some [bean defining annotation](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/2.0/cdi-spec.html#bean_defining_annotations).

Comment: Thanks @Siliarus, I have added SessionScoped annotation to BundleProducer. I have now this error: `Producers cannot produce unserializable instances for injection into an injection point that requires a passivation capable dependency
  Producer:  Producer Method [ResourceBundle] with qualifiers [@Bundle @Any] declared as [[BackedAnnotatedMethod] @Produces @Bundle public com.locale.BundleProducer.loadBundle(InjectionPoint)]
 at com.locale.BundleProducer.loadBundle(BundleProducer.java:15)
  Injection Point:  [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject @Bundle private com.security.PasswordBean.uiResources`

Comment: `@SessionScoped` seems out of place (but is not a source of the error you are now getting) - I would pick `@ApplicationScoped` or `@Dependent` instead. As for the error, it tells you the producer creates an unserializable instance (of `ResourceBundle`) and you are trying to inject it into `PasswordBean` which requires serializable fields - I suppose `PasswordBean` is `@SessionScoped`? In that case you have to make sure the producer method creates serializable bean.

Comment: With `@ApplicationScoped` I get : `An injection point has type InjectionPoint and qualifier @Default but bean declares not @Dependent scope.` right after the method signature `public ResourceBundle loadBundle(InjectionPoint ip)` And with `@Dependent` I get in runtime : `Producers cannot produce unserializable instances for injection into an injection point that requires a passivation capable dependency
  Producer:  Producer Method [ResourceBundle] with qualifiers [@Bundle @Any] declared as [[BackedAnnotatedMethod] @Produces @Bundle public com.locale.BundleProducer.loadBundle(InjectionPoint)]`

Comment: You are still not addressing the serializability issue, e.g. check that the bean you are injecting into really has to be serializable (do you need to have it session scoped? or any other serialization-requiring scope?). If so, start looking into how to produce `ResourceBundle` which will be serializable.

Comment: Things starts to be a little bit complicated for me, :( I have updated my code to include the class where I am trying to inject the bundle.

Comment: `java.util.ResourceBundle` is not serializable which blows up the serialization of whole `PasswordBean`. Easiest way of avoiding that is making that field `transient` - this means that should serialization occur, this field will be ignored.

Comment: A bit of ruffling through SO also gave me - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3000170 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35755944 where people bumped into `ResourceBundle` serialization problem. You can inspire there as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3270570/1227941) helped me to correct and run the code without any further Exception

```
@Inject
@com.locale.Bundle("com.locale.admin.user")
private transient ResourceBundle uiResources;
```

With **transient** to ResourceBundle.
Thanks a lot @Siliarus