# Hide some object fields from response with resteasy annotation

Tags: java, response, resteasy

Exists a resteasy annotation to hide some object fields?

For example I have

```
public class X {
    private int a;
    private int b;
    private int c;
}
```

When i check in the fiddler the front-end receive a,b and c but i only want to send a without create another response object (only with annotation on the field).

Can I do this? Exists an annotation?

Thank you.

Comment: Which framework do you use?

Comment: java ee and angular with resteasy

Comment: I assume therefore that Java EE is serializing instances of X to JSON, right?

Comment: Yes, it' s right.

Comment: Which application server are you using? JBoss?

Comment: Tomcat v8.5 . . .

Comment: are you looking for something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9112900/jackson-how-to-prevent-field-serialization

Answer (score 0):

I'm working with resteasy using jsonb.
The way I found to hide the field was by using @JsonbTransient in my getters. Every getter I need to hide, I noted with this.
In my case, I'm using Lombok and @Getter, so I had to manually recreate the specific getter. Try this:

```
@JsonbTransient
public String getB( ) {
    return b;
}
@JsonbTransient
public String getC( ) {
    return c;
}
```