# Jackson writeValueAsString calls unrelated getter

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

I'm working on a Spring MVC project and I'm trying to implement an anonymous chat. In one of the classes, named **Conversation**, I have several fields such as id, startDate, and preserved and some others. I want Jackson to ignore these other fields using the `@JsonIgnoreProperties` annotation, and I also want them to not be persisted in the database by using the `@Transient` annotation. I've generated the getters and setters using Lombok.

Initially, I had a code snippet that worked well. It was responsible for displaying a user's persisted conversations on the /conversations page. Here's the code snippet I was using:

```
model.addAttribute("conversations",
                objectMapper.writeValueAsString(userConversations));
```

This code has working fine until I've added field `randomTopics` and method `getRandomTopic()` to my **Conversation** class. The method is designed to get random topic if one of the users in conversation has requested it.

```
@Transient
private List<String> randomTopics;

//...

public String getRandomTopic() {
    return randomTopics.get(new Random().nextInt(randomTopics.size()));
}
```

The `randomTopics` list is initialized from a txt file and isn't stored in the database. The problem arises when a user wants to view their previous conversations. The application retrieves the conversations from the database, but the `randomTopics` field remains null. Strangely, Jackson seems to be calling the `getRandomTopic()` method during the mapping process, which causes a **JsonMappingException** and a **NullPointerException** in the `getRandomTopic()` method.

Interestingly, I noticed that if I remove the 'get' prefix from the method name (`getRandomTopic()` becomes `randomTopic()`), the issue disappears. However, the problem resurfaces if the method name starts with 'get'. Why does this happen?

There's another curious aspect: I also have a Map field in the same class, similar to the `randomTopics` list. This field is also ignored by Jackson, and it has a method that starts with "get" to retrieve some topic from Map. The difference lies in the return type of this method; it returns a custom class instead of a String. In this case, Jackson never calls the method (I verified this with a debugger).

Any insights into why this is happening would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time!

Comment: By default, Jackson treats methods starting with `get` as properties. You can annotate it with `@JsonIgnore` if you don't want it to be serialized.

Comment: Oh, now I see. Thanks for explanatory answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jackson: how to prevent field serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9112900/jackson-how-to-prevent-field-serialization)

Comment: Not really, I already knew how to prevent serialization, I just didn't understand why some getter is being called. But shmosel's answer clarified this.